# Database is getting deleted after getting updated (heroku) (discord.js)

Tags: database, discord, discord.js, enmap

Im discord developer and right now im using heroku to host my bot. Whenever i change something in the files in the github and heroku will automatically deploys the changes that i did. For no reason after getting updated, it deletes all the configuration(db) done by the admin per server. Is there any solution to fix it?

Comment: Are you pushing an empty db instance to the repository each time you change something? If so this will override any data the db used to hold

Comment: no im not pushing an empty db, i recently created a ping command in vs code and exported to github for testing as you know it doesnt need db for that. So heroku automatically starts deploying it, when i check the configuration of my server its gone.

Comment: Did you put something update query or something on your `client.on('ready')`?

Comment: yeah i use that event

Comment: Where is the database stored? Are you running any queries when the bot starts that would result in the database being cleared?

Comment: in enmap folder..it runs ig, because whenever i update my github, heroku used to deploy by itself. Dooes the db gets updated too? because in my github repo enmap db is empty...

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use MONGODB instead of heroku db ;-)

Comment: heroku db? also i aint comfortable using mongodb ;-;

Comment: ok then u have to find another db service

Comment: Fastest db is mongodb

Comment: enmap is yet another better db